# SQL How to align ranges of data points in rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

Suppose having the data set:

```
with
  data_table(title, x) as (
    select 'a', 1 from dual union all
    select 'a', 3 from dual union all
    select 'a', 4 from dual union all
    select 'a', 5 from dual union all
    select 'b', 1 from dual union all
    select 'b', 2 from dual union all
    select 'b', 3 from dual union all
    select 'b', 6 from dual
  )
select * from data_table;

 TITLE | X
-----------
  a      1
  a      3
  a      4
  a      5
  b      1
  b      2
  b      3
  b      6
```

Wee see that points related to `a` and `b` are different.

**How to align values in `X` column so both groups have the same points, filling the gaps with `NULL`?**

Expected result is:

```
 TITLE | X
-----------
  a     1
  a    NULL
  a     3
  a     4
  a     5
  a    NULL
  b     1
  b     2
  b     3
  b    NULL
  b    NULL
  b     6
```

Straightforward solution I got is

```
with
  data_table(title, x) as (
    select 'a', 1 from dual union all
    select 'a', 3 from dual union all
    select 'a', 4 from dual union all
    select 'a', 5 from dual union all
    select 'b', 1 from dual union all
    select 'b', 2 from dual union all
    select 'b', 3 from dual union all
    select 'b', 6 from dual
  ),
  all_points(x) AS (
    select distinct x from data_table
  ),
  all_titles(title) AS (
    select distinct title from data_table
  ),
  aligned_data(title, x) as (
    select t.title, p.x from all_points p cross join all_titles t
  )
  select ad.title, dt.x
    from aligned_data ad
    left join data_table dt on dt.title = ad.title and dt.x = ad.x
   order by ad.title, ad.x;
```

As wee see `cross join` in `aligned_data` definition is bottleneck and can kill performance on valuable data sets.

I wonder if this task could be solved more elegantly. Maybe a trick with window functions can be proposed.